# Android equivalent of windows %COMPUTERNAME% as php parameter

Tags: php, android, parameters

I'm writhing an intranet system using html / php & javascript. I've been able to pass the windows computername as a PHP paramter using the testpage.php?Device_Name=%COMPUTERNAME% for the windows based system. Is there an equivalent parameter I can use for an Android version ? ie the android equivalent of %COMPUTERNAME% ?

Comment: Phones do not usually have names. What *specifically* are you looking for as a value from a phone?

Comment: Hi, they will be android wifi scanners and it's the 'device name' that I'm trying to pass as a parameter ( if it's possible ) But I do not want to try and get the device name once the page is loaded.

Comment: Again: phones do not have a "device name".

Comment: This project is not going to run on a phone, it will run on an android wifi scanner ( specifically a Zebra MC2200 ) and these devices do in fact have a 'device name'. to access it you go to the settings / about option and the first entry is Device name ( their terminology, not mine ) I can change this value - which is defaulted to MC2200 - but I can give it a unique reference. As a confirmation prior to changing - it gives me a message  saying " Your Device Name is visible to apps on your phone. It may also be seen by other people when you connect to Bluetooth devices or setup a wifi hotspot"

Comment: sorry if the last post was abrupt, as I ran out of characters. So what I'm trying to do is pass any device unique value ( either one I can change or a device generated value ) as a parameter in the URL query string - it doesn't have to be the 'device name' it can be anything that is accessible to the query string and unique to the device - I have screen shots of the device name option ( original value / accessing the update / confirmation message prior to update / changed value )- but I have no idea how to get them into this comment

Comment: "and these devices do in fact have a 'device name'" -- you will need to ask Zebra how to get that value. It might map to something in the Android SDK, or it might be something that you can get via some Zebra SDK.